# Is there a function in Base R that convert fractions to doubles

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that includes both pure fractions, integers with fractions and pure integers. Is there a base R function that can convert these string values to doubles.

For example:

```
df <- c("1 1/4", "1/2", "12 3/4", "1")
df2 <- function(df)
df2

>>(1.25,0.5,12.75,1.0)
```

Or do I need to write a function for this?